# Oracle Forms - Error 103, Encountered the symbol “ORDER”

Tags: sql, oracleforms

I am using below query in my forms but it throws this error:

> Oracle Forms - Error 103, Encountered the symbol “END”.

Same query its working on toad, there is no issue.

Is there any limitation to use ORDER by in forms or in sub query or as select table ?

Forms 6i
oracle 10g

```
SELECT apr_rate 
INTO lv_apr_rate      
FROM 
(SELECT apr_rate                                                                                                  
     FROM cm_contract_extension
    WHERE country_code = '044' 
      AND company_code = '0441' 
      AND contract_number = '0000002140426510'
      AND supply_sequence_number = 1  
      ORDER BY version_number DESC)
        WHERE ROWNUM < 2 ;
```

BR,
Shadab Hussain

Comment: If you are using at the block level, there is a block level property to specify which column the block should `ORDER BY` rather than specifying `ORDER BY` explicitly in SQL.

Comment: No, I am not using at the block level.

Answer (score 0):

Forms doesn't let you use ORDER BY, if you want that you'd need to write it as a database procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can write this using `KEEP`:

```
SELECT MAX(apr_rate) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY version_number DESC) as apr_rate                                                                                                  
FROM cm_contract_extension
WHERE country_code = '044' AND
      company_code = '0441' AND
      contract_number = '0000002140426510' AND
      supply_sequence_number = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, This make sense but here only problem will be performance issue as my table is very huge so I can not use DENSE_RANK. Is there any other way apert from DENSE_RANK ?

Comment: `KEEP` has had very good performance when I have used it, even on large tables.